# how to change background color of the selected menu on toolbar in android?

Tags: android

I dynamically added menus in my application. But if there are many menus then it will difficult to know which menu is currently selected. So I want to change background color of selected menu  or at least change text color of selected menu item.

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
         menu.clear();

                if (!(courseNameList == null))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < courseNameList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        Course c = courseNameList.get(i);
                        menu.add(0, c.getCourse_id(), 0, c.getCourse_name());
                    }
                }
                menu.add("About Us");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int courseId = item.getItemId(); //CourseId
        String courseName = item.getTitle().toString();  //course name

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Here courseNameList is dynamic object list which contains course name, id .It is added in menu. So app user should know which menu is currently selected.

Comment: can you please paste some code here , it would be better to understand @Priyanka G

Comment: I think u have to use setTag and getTag or setId and getId methods to remember the menus.

Comment: Can u give one example to how to used setTag or getTag with menus?

Comment: but I think u have id and position both then wat is the problem? @Priyanka G

Comment: I got item id on selection of menu. But I don't understand how to change background or text color of selected menu?

Comment: you got it or not still?